# ReflectionPermission not granted even though Trust level is High

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7.5, code-access-security

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET 2.0 app on Windows 2008, IIS 7.5. The app throws this exception:

> SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.]

EVEN THOUGH the app is running at `trust level = "Full"` as specified in the `web.config`. And yes, the framework web.config is configured to allow trust level override.

I have a feeling something about the security policies on the box are preventing the app from actually running at this level of trust, even though we're explicitly instructing it to.  The app runs fine in dev on Win7.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved up after "Unblocking" a particular dll, and its pdb and xml files.  (Right-click, Properties, click "Unblock" button.)